# dropdown menu is covered

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have problem like this
[dropdown-menu covered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkshZ.png)

btw it isn't covered by other div, but dropdown-menu can't be out of the navbar, if i can ilustrate this it can be like this

[ilustration of the navbar and dropdown-men](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5YVY.png)

i make the navbar native with this code

```
        <div id="topnav" class="topnav close-sidebar">
            <div class="col d-inline">
                <a href="#" onclick="sidebarToggle()">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                </a>
                <p class="mt-1" style="text-align: left; font: normal normal normal 14px/17px Helvetica; letter-spacing: 0.34px;"><%: DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") %></p>
            </div>


            <div class="form-inline mr-5" style="max-width: 350px;">
                <div class="d-inline">
                    <img class="mb-3" src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Assets/img/Worklist/atom-button-header-a-button-header-icon.svg")%>" alt="Alternate Text" />

                </div>
                <div class="d-inline mb-3">
                    <img style="height: 24px;" class="" src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Assets/img/Worklist/atom-icon-a-icon-globe.svg")%>" alt="Alternate Text" />
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline mb-3">
                    <div id="en" class="">EN</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-inline" style="max-width: 250px;">
                    <div id="profile" class="text-right mb-3 ml-4" style="max-width: 250px; width: 150px;">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <div style="cursor: pointer;" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="d-inline">
                                    <img style="height: 32px; width: 32px;" src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Assets/img/Worklist/img_avatar.png") %>" class="img-fluid mr-2 rounded-circle" alt="Responsive image" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-inline">
                                    Nama User
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-inline">
                                    <img src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Assets/img/Worklist/atom-icon-a-icon-angle-down.svg") %>" alt="Text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="opacity: 1 !important; z-index: 99;">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the css of is like this

```
.topnav {
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 56px;
    background: #1D2567 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.close-sidebar {
    margin-left: 56px;
}
```

for the dropdown-menu i used boostrap 4.3.1

when i inspect the web, the css is like this

[css inspect 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWsOa.png)

[css inspect 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s7ev.png)

[css inspect 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGAg.png)

[css inspect 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTXew.png)

Update:

i try to see my z-index using 3d view in ms edge, and the dropdown-menu is already in front of the navbar, but on the website it is covered

[3D View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA5sR.png)

Comment: You can use `z-index` for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set position relative to parent or container and set position absolute to child elements.  try to change overflow

```
    .topnav {
top: 0;
overflow: hidden; // try to change this not hidden
height: 56px;
background: #1D2567 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
opacity: 1;
display: flex;
position: relative; // parent}

.close-sidebar {
margin-left: 56px;
position: absolute; // child};
```

if dont work let us to know and type more describe. thank you

Comment: solved if i remove "overflow: hidden;" but i didn't add the other, by the way thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
.topnav {
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 56px;
    background: #1D2567 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.close-sidebar {
    margin-left: 56px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This should work. Let us know if this doesn't

Comment: it doesn't work, and my navbar being messy  [My Navbar Being Messy Like This][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bONTS.png

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
.topnav {
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 56px;
    background: #1D2567 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 999;
}

.close-sidebar {
    margin-left: 56px;
}
```